# Oracle.DataAccess.Client and .NET Framework errors in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, .net-framework, power-query, oracle-12c

When trying to access an Oracle 12c Database through Excel and Power Query, I received an error stating

```
The recommended provider("Oracle.DataAccess.Client") is not installed.  You 
can continue with your current provider, however it has been deprecated and 
may not work correctly.
```

I went through Microsoft's own guide (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-an-oracle-database-power-query-d7fbd231-a705-4eb7-83b3-a66bfb678395?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to install the ODAC.  My specs are:

```
Windows 10 64-Bit
Excel for Office 365 MSO (16.0.11425.20200) 64-bit
Oracle 12c
```

So, following the microsoft guide, I installed

```
64-bit ODAC 12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4) Xcopy for Windows x64
```

(i've also tried releases 1 & 2 and the non-Xcopy versions of each, to no avail).  The ODAC 12c Release 4 includes the following:

```
    64-bit Oracle Data Provider for .NET 4 12.1.0.2.0
    64-bit Oracle Data Provider for .NET 2.0 12.1.0.2.0
    64-bit Oracle Providers for ASP.NET 4 12.1.0.2.0
    64-bit Oracle Providers for ASP.NET 2.0 12.1.0.2.0
    64-bit Oracle Provider for OLE DB 12.1.0.2.0
    64-bit Oracle Services for Microsoft Transaction Server 12.1.0.2.0
    64-bit Oracle Instant Client 12.1.0.2.0
```

When trying to connect to an Oracle database within Excel I get multiple errors:

First, I Click on

```
Data > Get Data > From Database > From Oracle Database
```

A messagebox/error appears stating

```
The recommended provider("Oracle.DataAccess.Client") is not installed.  You 
can continue with your current provider, however it has been deprecated and 
may not work correctly.
```

I'm not sure why this message would appear, when I installed the Microsoft recommended ODAC.  Nevertheless, I click

```
'OK'
```

An inputbox appears with title:

```
Oracle database
```

In the Server field I type:

```
%HOSTNAME%:%PORT%\%SERVICE_NAME%
```

A new error message appears:

```
"Unable to Connect"
"We encountered an error while tyring to connect."
Details: "Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data 
Provider.. This is a configuration issue with the file 
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config'."
```

At this point I am unable to continue and cannot connect to the Oracle database.    Any and all insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle Client install is an absolute nightmare. I've wasted so much time on it over the years.  I got one machine working using Oracle 11 so I'm trying to hold onto that for as long as possible ...

I suspect the ODAC on it's own is not sufficient, I would try installing the full Oracle Client with Admin option first, then adding the ODAC on top.